# Que erro é esse javax.servlet.ServletException: getOutputStream()?

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, ireport

Estou gerando um relatório, no momento em que clico para emitir e ele exibe esse erro.

*Exception*:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response 
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606) 
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
```

*Root cause*:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response 
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:614) 
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:199) 
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.getResponseOutputWriter(ExternalContextImpl.java:723) 
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.createResponseWriter(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:938) 
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:377) 
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125) 
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121) 
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) 
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) 
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) 
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
```

Alguém sabe o que esse erro representa?

Esse método é o que está gerando o erro, todos os outros relatórios que vem dessa página estão normais.

```java
public void emitirRelPlanoEnsino() {

    this.relatorio.put("CURSO", this.ieSelecionada.getId());
    this.relatorio.put("PERIODOLETIVO", this.perLetivo.getId());
    this.relatorio.put("DISCIPLINA", this.planoEnsino.getDisciplina()
            .getId());
    this.relatorio.put("DOCENTE", this.planoEnsino.getDocente().getId());
    this.relatorio.put("CABECALHO", this.caminhoCab);
    this.relatorio.put("SUBREPORT_DIR", this.caminho + "/template_header/");
    this.relatorio.put("SUBREPORTCONT_DIR", this.caminho + "/acad/");
    this.relatorio.put("SUBREPORTBB_DIR", this.caminho + "/acad/");
    this.relatorio
            .put("SUBNODATA_DIR", this.caminho + "/template_no_data/");
    try {
        GeraRelatorio.executarRelatorio(
                "/jasperlt/acad/reportPlanoEnsino.jasper", this.relatorio);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JSFUtil.addInfoMessage("Erro ao gerar o relatório");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

View

```xml
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <p:commandButton value="Emitir" icon="ui-icon-print"
        action="#{relGestCursoBacking.gerarRelatorioPlano}"
        title="Clique para gerar o relatório" ajax="false"
        onclick="this.form.target='_blank'" update=":growl" />
    <p:commandButton value="Limpar" icon="ui-icon-cancel"
        actionListener="#{relGestCursoBacking.limpar}" ajax="true"
        process="@this" title="Clique para limpar o formulário"
        update="tblRel" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

**Edição:** *stacktrace* completa

```
10:25:01,407 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) Error Rendering View[/curso/reportGestaoCurso.xhtml]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:614) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:199) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.getResponseOutputWriter(ExternalContextImpl.java:723) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.createResponseWriter(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:938) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:377) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79) [primefaces-3.4.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]

10:25:01,424 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/sigaac].[Faces Servlet]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:614) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:199) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.getResponseOutputWriter(ExternalContextImpl.java:723) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.createResponseWriter(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:938) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:377) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79) [primefaces-3.4.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
```

Comment: coloque o código que gera esse erro para ficar mais facil de ajudar

Comment: Como está sua view? Você sempre o mesmo botão, por exemplo `p:commandButton` para todos os relatórios, inclusive os que funcionam?

Comment: Nos outros relatórios o metodo que os gera é diferentes e estão em outra <p:tab>

Comment: O trecho da *view* que incluiu chama `gerarRelatorioPlano` do MB e você incluiu a *action*  `emitirRelPlanoEnsino`. É a mesma coisa?

Comment: O gerarRelatorioPlano chama o emitir. é apenas o método de chamada.

Comment: Não tem nada nele? Apenas chama, não tem nada como um `responseComplete`?

Comment: Não. Apenas a chamada.   public void gerarRelatorioPlano(){
  emitirRelPlanoEnsino();
 }

Comment: Cara, muito estranho. Teste `h:commandButton` e se continuar o erro é algo no seu MB ou esse cara que gera o relatório... Sem ver mais código fica difícil falar o que é.

Comment: Blz Bruno... Vou dar uma olhada aqui e depois te conte o que era. Vlw

Comment: @MarcosRaiAlvesdaCunha, tá um pouco obscuto ainda, mas você já tentou dar uma olhada nesse link, parece que o cara teve o mesmo problema:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776142/getoutputstream-has-already-been-called-for-this-response

Comment: Galera... a falha estava no relatório que me enviaram... tinha um inner join que não existia lá... Essas coisas acontecem...